# properly delete files for flash drives, but still retain trash bin

Tags: delete, trash

I'm finding that in Ubuntu 15.04 if I trash a file on my flash drive, like some music, that the stereo in my car still finds it and plays it. Is it because it's in a recycle bin / trash can sort of thing?

If so, how can I always get external flash drives to permanently delete files instead of using a recycle bin thing, but still have a recycle bin for my normal "permanent" hard drives?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the deleted files will be put in the hidden directory `.Trash` inside the media. Use <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>DELETE</kbd> instead of just <kbd>DELETE</kbd> to bypass the trash and permanently delete files. For the files in your internal hard drives you can use just <kbd>DELETE</kbd> which will put them in the trash.